# Objects within <Menu> have their MouseOver border overridden

Tags: c#, wpf

I have unusual items like a button, ComboBox, CheckBox, etc., in a "Menu" container. The problem is that the MouseOver border for these controls gets overridden somehow, only when they are in that  container. Anywhere else, they are fine.

Every control (CheckBoxes, ComboBoxes, Buttons, Labels, etc) has a custom style. This custom style works fine unless these controls are placed in a "Menu". When that happens I get this blue border highlight for some reason for non MenuItem objects. What can I do to fix the border color without moving or changing other controls?

Here is minimal code that reproduces the problem:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero2" x:Name="myWindow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MyTitle"
        Width="560" Height="180" 
        MinWidth="560" MinHeight="180"
        Background="#FF222222" Foreground="Red" BorderBrush="#FF222222" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="None" Opacity="0.75" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner">
    <Window.Resources>
        <sys:Double x:Key="height">40</sys:Double>
        <sys:Double x:Key="titleBarSize">36</sys:Double>
        <sys:Double x:Key="fontSize">16</sys:Double>
        <Color x:Key="backgroundColor">#FF222222</Color>
        <Brush x:Key="backgroundColorBrush">#FF222222</Brush>
        <Color x:Key="highlightedColor">#FF333333</Color>
        <Brush x:Key="highlightedColorBrush">#FF333333</Brush>
        <Color x:Key="borderColor">#FF333333</Color>
        <Brush x:Key="borderColorBrush">#FF333333</Brush>
        <Color x:Key="textColor">#FF999999</Color>
        <Brush x:Key="textColorBrush">#FF999999</Brush>
        <Brush x:Key="titleBarColorBrush">#FF222222</Brush>
        <Thickness x:Key="Tab_Border_Thickness">2,2,2,2</Thickness>
        <Thickness x:Key="TabItem_Border_Thickness_Selected">2,2,2,0</Thickness>      

        <!--Button-->
        <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource backgroundColorBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource backgroundColorBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource textColorBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="{StaticResource height}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource fontSize}"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{StaticResource backgroundColorBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{StaticResource backgroundColorBrush}" 
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
                                              SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource highlightedColorBrush}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource highlightedColorBrush}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource highlightedColorBrush}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource highlightedColorBrush}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource highlightedColorBrush}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource backgroundColorBrush}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource backgroundColorBrush}"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource textColorBrush}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Menu x:Name="menu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="560">
            <Button x:Name="button1" Content="button 1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"  Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle1}"/>
        </Menu>
        <Button x:Name="button2" Content="button 2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,54,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"  Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle1}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Some screens? Code parts?

Comment: The code is Huge. The problem could be anywhere. It could be something I need to add to a custom MenuStyle1 style. The fix could also be some special syntax that tells the form, "no, FU. Use the style I said to use"

Comment: Every control has something like Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxItemStyle1}"/> and works perfectly fine, unless it is in a Menu container.

Comment: _"The code is Huge. The problem could be anywhere"_ -- that is _exactly_ why you are expected to take the time to create and provide to us [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces your problem. Also provide a clear, precise explanation of what that code does and how _exactly_ that is different from what you want it to do. And make sure all pertinent details are provided _in the question_. Do not use comments to add details.

Comment: I added the a minimal code example that reproduces the problem. I have zero confidence in the idea that that will help solve the problem in this specific, specific case. The reason why is that that idea assumes there is just some error or typo, that once fixed, will solve the problem. Not the case. This is some retarded WPF-related gotcha' that you will only be able to solve if it has happened to you before.